# ASP.NET Core Web Api doesn´t load template,how can i solve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I need help. I have been trying to solve the problem for the last few days without success. I'm following the tutorial, in the tutorial a person enters the ASP.NET-Web-API, loads it and then starts running an empty project, which is otherwise possible. In my case, unfortunately, it was not, I downloaded everything and one package in the vs installer that has .net in its name, so that's not it. I downloaded asp.net and web development, .net desktop development, everything, everything, unfortunately without success. I have restored, uninstalled, installed VS several times, I even went to the option to reload all packages, unfortunately all without success.
Help please

And no,the project in not just hidden,its missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: inadequate info, you need to share necessary screenshots & describe clearly your issue. From what you said, it does look like issue with setting up visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your Solution Explorer here is completely empty, that is to say, it is not because of the lack of sdk or .net version. If it is the above two problems there will at least be a solution you created.

Here is a solution that once solved this problem:

1. Close Visual Studio first;
2. Delete all files and folders in the C:/Users//AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/17.0xxx/ComponentModelCache folder;
3. Re-open VS, open the solution again, and you can see the project information in the solution explorer.

If the above solution does not work, please open cmd and enter dotnet --info to see the information after execution.